# Can I specify 'greater than' with db_delete()?

Tags: database, 8

I am new to Drupal 8. 
I can use the following code to delete a record where salary == 45

```
$salary = 45;
$num_deleted = db_delete('test_table')
  ->condition('salary', $salary)
  ->execute();
```

Is it possible to specify a condition like "salary >= $salary" with db_delete() or I should use db_query()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see document [Conditional clauses](https://www.drupal.org/node/310086) for 7 (**need update document**) or you can see the documentation for [`QueryInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/interface/QueryInterface/8.1.x), in particular for [`QueryInterface::condition()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Acondition/8.1.x).

> @param $operator  Possible values: - '=', '<>', '>', '>=', '<', '<=',
>
> - 'STARTS_WITH', 'CONTAINS', 
>     'ENDS_WITH': These operators expect $value to be a literal of the same type as the column.
> - 'IN', 'NOT IN': These operators expect $value to be an array of literals of the same type as the column.
> - 'BETWEEN': This operator expects $value to be an array of two literals  of the same type as the column.

. In your case you can use:

```
$salary = 45;
$num_deleted = db_delete('test_table')
  ->condition('salary', $salary, '>=')
  ->execute();
```